# What could cause this pointer to be corrupted?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, intel-fpga, heap-corruption

First of all, this code is running without any issue on my linux desktop pc (x86_64) but on my Cyclone v (arm cpu/fpga), I have a segmentation fault because the value of the pointer is changing. The relevant line is the last one, during the for loop, the value of "layer->filename" is changing, it is correct during the first iteration (the address given by malloc) but it changes on the second one.

Basically, this bit of code is copying character from "buff" to "layer->filename", as you can see in the output file, the value of buff[i] is a valid character so it should not corrupt layer->filename.

If you have an idea of what could cause this issue, please let me know.

Thank you for your help.

```
typedef enum 
{ 
    CONV,
    BN, 
    FC, 

} layer_type;

typedef struct layer{
    layer_type layer_type;
    int shape[3];
    char *filename;
} layer;

...

layer *layer=malloc(sizeof(layer));

char buff[30];

int i;
...

layer->filename = malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));

if(buff[0]=='b')
    layer->layer_type=BN;
else if(buff[0]=='c')
    layer->layer_type=CONV;
else
    layer->layer_type=FC;
for(i=0; i<n ; i++)
    *(layer->filename+i)=buff[i];
```

[values of buff[i] and layer->name during the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPtyL.png)

Comment: `*(layer->filename+i)` why do you write code like that?

Comment: What is `n`?????

Comment: while reading a line from a text file, n is the number of character before a white space, I get filename is of size n+1 because I add a '\0' character after copying the filename I get from the text file.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<n ; i++) *(layer->filename+i)=buff[i];` can be `memcpy(layer->filename, buff, sizeof(char)*n);` Oh, it seems you forgot to initialize the last element of the buffer assigned to `layer->filename`.

Comment: Note that in your loop `for(i=0; i<n ; i++)`, `*(layer->filename+i)=buff[i];` will _not_ null-terminate the filename. To do that, either do it explicitly or write `for(i=0; i<=n ; i++)`.

Comment: yes it is done after the loop, it's not shown in this bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum 
{ 
    CONV,
    BN, 
    FC, 

} layer_type;

typedef struct layer{
    layer_type layer_type;
    int shape[3];
    char *filename;
} layer;

size_t test(size_t x) {
    printf("%d\n", (int)x);
    return x;
}

int main(void) {
    layer *layer=malloc(test(sizeof(layer)));
    return 0;
}
```

You can see that `sizeof(layer)` in the line

```
layer *layer=malloc(sizeof(layer));
```

is not the size of a structure but the size of a pointer.

This is because the name of variable is the same as the type name and the compiler treated `layer` in `sizeof` as the variable (pointer) name.

To avoid this and have it allocate the size of structure, you should change the name of type or variable to avoid confusion.

Dereferincing the pointer

```
layer *layer=malloc(sizeof(*layer));
```

also can solve this problem, but I think renaming is better.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler takes the variable and not the type of the same name?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but you are right using the same name is not a good idea

Comment: So I checked the sizeof(layer) is 20 Bytes.

Comment: @CitizenAA289 How did you do the check?

Comment: @MikeCAT I put a printf before the malloc and I printed sizeof(layer).

Comment: @CitizenAA289 You mean before the variable declaration? If so, your check is invalid.

Comment: @MikeCAT It was that after I changed the name it worked.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you for your help. I was asking for trouble with those name.